# Have getchar only read one character

Tags: c

I have a code where I am reading in two characters.

```
char a;
char b;

a = getchar();
getchar();

b = getchar();
getchar();

printf("%c%c", a, b);
```

The code works well if the user follows the rules but if he inputs more than one character at one time the results get strange.

for example
aa+b>a

or it skips the second getchar and jumps to the printf

```
aaa>aa
asdf>ad
qwertz>qe
```

How can I make the program display an error if the user enters more than one character at the same time or just read in the first one?

Comment: I don't understand your output examples.  Nothing can get "skipped" in your code as there is no conditional.  getchar() reads the next character in the input stream.  See this example - http://rabbit.eng.miami.edu/class/een218/getchar.html

Comment: Are you hoping the discarded values from the second and fourth `getchar` are `'\n'`?

Comment: What I am saying is that the program has to inputs. One for char a and one for char b. But if I put in more than one character in the first it seems to assign a value for b and jump to prinft which should only happen after i put in a value for the second character b.

Comment: Yeah. When I didn't have the getchar() s; after the input it skipped the 2nd input and entered the value of the first input for both inputs

Comment: You seem to be confusing characters with strings... `getchar()` only reads one letter/digit/etc., not a whole line.

Comment: That's what I want. But I want my program to give out errors when the users inputs more than one character.

Comment: What he probably wants is no buffering of input by either user or kernel. The answer is OS specific and he didn't specify.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int inputFirstOne(void){
    int ch;

    ch = getchar();
    while('\n'!=getchar());

    return ch;
}

int main(){
    char a, b;

    a = inputFirstOne();
    b = inputFirstOne();
    printf("%c%c\n", a, b);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The second `getchar` is used to capture the `newline` character or the keypress of enter.It has a ascii value of 10.Just verify wether the second `getchar` reads newline.

```
char a;
char b,ch;

a = getchar();
ch = getchar();
if(ch!=10)//newline
    //error

b = getchar();

ch = getchar();
if(ch!=10)//newline
    //error

printf("%c%c", a, b);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `getchar` macro takes the next available character from the input stream.   Period.

It doesn't prompt, or wait for the user, or anything like that.  If they've already entered a character and it hasn't yet been read, then that will be used.

If you want keystroke-level access from C, you need to do more work, preferably by using a library like `ncurses` or `termios`