# Inputing a single character in c

Tags: c

I have a short program in which I want the user to input a capital letter followed by a second input of a capital letter which will be an offset.  The program then works out the value of the new letter based on the offset letter.  The problem is my program only seems to allow the first letter to be entered.  I am assuming this is because of the return key is seen as the second input.  I am not to sure how to overcome this problem.

Can anyone offer advise.

Below is my code:

```
/*********************************************
*             ASCII CHARACTER PROG           *
**********************************************/

#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
char ch1;
char offset;
int value = 0;

// USER ENTERS A CAPITAL LETTER
printf("please enter a capital character:  ");
ch1=getchar();
printf("\n");

// USER ASKED TO ENTER ANOTHER CAPITAL LETTER AS AN OFFSET 
printf("please enter a capital character as an offset:  ");
offset=getchar();
printf("\n");

//CALCULATES THE NEW LETTER VALUE BASED ON THE OFFSET
value = offset + (ch1 - 'A');

// ENSURES THE VALUE WILL STAY WITHIN 65 - 90
if (value > 90)
{
    value = value - 26;
}

printf("the value of the new character is: %d", value);
printf("\n");


return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on "calculate offset"? Do you mean just convert both characters to integer representation and then add them together to obtain a new character or?

Answer (score 0):

You can consume the newline character with

```
ch1=getchar(); getchar();
```

Comment: This could be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20295686/have-getchar-only-read-one-character?rq=1

Comment: Thank you for such a simple solution it works perfectly.